# How to Paginate a MySql Ranking Query

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I have the following ranking query working fine with a limit of 25 records per page, it shows 1st - 25th for the first 25 records, but when i go to the next page, the rank stays the same 1st - 25th when it should say 26th - 50th.

```
("SELECT image, name, wins, losses, level, xp, wins
 AS W, losses AS L, TRUNCATE(wins/IF(wins=0,1,wins+losses)*100,0)
  AS PCT, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank FROM teams p, 
  (SELECT @curRank := 0) r WHERE `console` = 3 AND `game` = 23
   AND `laddertype` = 1 ORDER BY xp 
   DESC LIMIT " . mysql_real_escape_string($limit) . ", 25");

//get page
$page = 0;
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {           
    $rank = mysql_query("SELECT image, name, wins, losses, level, xp, wins AS W, losses AS L, TRUNCATE(wins/IF(wins=0,1,wins+losses)*100,0) AS PCT, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank FROM `teams` p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r WHERE `console` = 3 AND `game` = 23 AND `laddertype` = 1 AND `id` = ".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id'])." LIMIT 1");
    $rank = mysql_fetch_assoc($rank);
    $rank = $rank['rank'];
    $page = ceil($rank/25)-1;
}
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $page = (int)$_GET['page'];
}
$limit = $page * 25;



//do pagination
$teamcount = $teamtotal['COUNT(*)'];
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $urlstring = '//website.com/?id='.$_GET['id'];
}else{
    $urlstring = '//website.com/';
}
$template['PAGINATION'] = getpages($urlstring, (ceil($teamcount / 25) - 1), $page);
```

how do i get the rank column to change with the pagination?

Comment: Modify the starting value for your rank calculation accordingly …?

Answer (score 1):

i figured it out, i needed to set `(SELECT @curRank := 0)`  to this instead `(SELECT @curRank := $limit)`